# How do I get current user logged in to windows?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am an active directory user and I am simply trying to print the name of the current user out in a `Respnse.Write()` method. From what I read from several other questions posted here I need to use

```
using System.Security.Principal;
string username = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name
```

However, when I try to write the username to the screen I get

**NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE**

instead of

**domain\12345678**

Here is the code I am using to write to the screen:

```
Response.Write(WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name);
```

and I have identity impersonate set to true in my web.config. What do I do next?

***Edited to show suggested answers***

my pageload

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string userName = User.Identity.Name; 
    Response.Write(userName);
    //currently returning null
}
```

Comment: try turning on windows authentication in IIS and looking in Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_USER"]; for the username

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get at the current users windows identity](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5230441/how-to-get-at-the-current-users-windows-identity)

Comment: @WraithNath currently, authentication mode is set to windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason your approach isn't working is because `User.Identity` isn't physically referencing your *Active Directory Membership*.  For all intensive purposes, is trying to grab your active user through *Internet Information Systems (IIS)* which it can't do in the current state.  Since your utilizing Web-Forms, the easiest approach would be:

- `<asp:LoginView>` :  The following template will allow you to specify visible data for an anonymous user, logged in user, or logged out user.  Which will help manage your membership system accordingly.
- *Membership Not Needed* - Membership isn't regulated, but would like to display or access whom is logged in for certain instances.

To implement:

```
<connectionStrings>
     <add name="ADConnectionString" connectionString="LDAP://..." />
</connectionStrings>
```

That will be your `connectionString` to your directory.  Now to ensure the application authenticates correctly:

```
<authentication mode="Windows">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="2880" />
</authentication>
<membership>
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="MyADMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.ActiveDirectoryMembershipProvider, System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" connectionStringName="ADConnectionString" />
  </providers>
</membership>
```

Now you'll be able to properly run `User.Identity`.

Hopefully that helps.

Answer (score 3):

In your web.config you need `authentication mode` switched on to `Windows` and you need to disabled anonymous users

```
<system.web>
  <authentication mode="Windows" />
    <anonymousIdentification enabled="false" />
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
</system.web>
```

Comment: I did this and it still get `NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE` as a print out.

Comment: @Skullomania Do what's said in this answer, but also use `User.Identity.Name` to get the username in your code.

Comment: i kept the changes you requested in the webconfig and in the page_load I used `string userName = User.Identity.Name;Response.Write(userName);` and userName returns a null value

Comment: Are you doing this in IE? You may need check `Enable Integrated Windows Authentication` in the `Options` > `Advanced` tab.  Also don't use `Response.Write`, create a label or literal and write to that.

Answer (score 0):

```
string yourVariable = User.Identity.Name;
```

Comment: I kind of figured he knew what to do with the string afterwards :)